# What does WinPhone's Accelerometer Readings mean?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, accelerometer, sensors

I'd like to learn the approximate velocity and distance the phone is moved. I've decided to use MotionReading.DeviceAcceleration for that purpose. Documentation says about it:

The raw data readings from the Accelerometer class include the force of gravity on the device in addition to forces caused by the user moving the device. The DeviceAcceleration property gives the acceleration of the device without the inclusion of gravity.

The idea is to integrate over the values of accelerometer. Time span between the readings is a constant value, so it can be ignored.

I've moved the device from right to left along the x-axis, recording all the accelerometer's readings. Then I've build a graph of that values depending on time and expected to see two waves for the acceleration. The first one - above the time axis - when the movement was started, and the second one - under the time axis for the deceleration.

After integrating accelerometer's readings I expected to see the graph of the velocity as a wave above the time axis - increasing from zero and then decreasing back.

But here is what I've got. Raw accelerometer's readings: _https://imageshack.com/a/img10/5439/xf05.png

Values after the first integration: _https://imageshack.com/a/img199/3306/u80.png

Values after the second integration: _https://imageshack.com/a/img89/763/vvb.png

So, the first integration seems to be the two waves of the acceleration, described above. It does not return to zero due to usual accelerometer's errors, but it's ok.

And the second integration looks like a single wave of the speed (it finishes under the axis only because of acceleration error on previous step).

Does it mean the accelerometer gives me not the acceleration, but the changes of the acceleration?

Hope, my explanation is clear. Thanks ahead of time.